# Why is `apt update` fetching half a gigabyte of package lists?

Tags: apt, dpkg

Is it normal for `apt update` to fetch half a gigabyte of package files? I have a vague memory of it not taking this long at one point, but for some time now it's been fetching these huge package lists when I update. I'm curious whether this is normal.

The output of `apt update` is [in this paste](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/bbQsrvMXf8/). The particularly relevant part is `Fetched 478 MB in 1min 38s (4,883 kB/s)`. I can provide other dumps if necessary.

```
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                           
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                                                        
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tatokis/ckb-next/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                            
Get:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [3,023 B]                                                                                                                                         
Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]                                                                                                                                      
Get:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease [8,041 B]                                                                                                                                          
Get:8 http://www.geogebra.net/linux stable InRelease [8,690 B]                                                                                                                                                    
Get:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease [3,065 B]                                                                                                                                  
Get:10 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease [11.9 kB]                                                                                                                                                
Hit:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                                                                                                             
Hit:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                         
Get:13 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ungoogled_chromium/Ubuntu_Focal  InRelease [1,553 B]                                                    
Hit:14 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                                                          
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                           
Ign:16 https://celestia.space/packages focal InRelease                                     
Get:17 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]                   
Hit:18 https://celestia.space/packages focal Release                                       
Get:19 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages [59.8 kB]
Get:20 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages [59.1 kB]
Get:21 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages [59.5 kB]
Get:22 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2,368 kB]
Get:23 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [785 kB]
Get:24 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [385 kB]
Get:25 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [386 kB]
Get:26 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [408 kB]
Get:27 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [275 kB]
Get:28 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates i386 Contents (deb) [72.4 MB]
Get:29 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 Packages [171 kB]
Err:13 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ungoogled_chromium/Ubuntu_Focal  InRelease  
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 02456C79B2FD48BF home:ungoogled_chromium OBS Project <home:ungoogled_chromium@build.opensuse.org>
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [556 kB]
Get:31 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates amd64 Contents (deb) [168 MB]
Get:32 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,061 B]          
Get:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1,993 kB]                                        
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [326 kB]                    
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [59.9 kB]                
Get:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security amd64 Contents (deb) [155 MB]                      
Get:38 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [16.3 kB]                  
Get:39 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1,595 kB]
Get:40 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [224 kB]            
Get:41 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,024 kB]                 
Get:42 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [710 kB]
Get:43 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [237 kB]
Get:44 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security i386 Contents (deb) [65.8 MB]       
Get:45 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [407 kB]            
Get:46 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [23.5 kB]              
Get:47 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]             
Get:48 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,960 B]              
Get:49 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.5 kB]              
Get:50 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [12.0 kB]                                                                                                                       
Get:51 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [1,495 kB]                                                                                                                      
Get:52 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [211 kB]                                                                                                                        
Get:53 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [579 kB]                                                                                                                           
Get:54 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [794 kB]                                                                                                                          
Get:55 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [154 kB]                                                                                                                          
Get:56 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [94.2 kB]                                                                                                                  
Get:57 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [16.9 kB]                                                                                                                   
Get:58 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [22.9 kB]                                                                                                                       
Get:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse Translation-en [5,488 B]                                                                                                                       
Get:60 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]                                                                                                                  
Get:61 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [528 B]                                                                                                                   
Fetched 478 MB in 1min 38s (4,883 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
46 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ungoogled_chromium/Ubuntu_Focal  InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 02456C79B2FD48BF home:ungoogled_chromium OBS Project <home:ungoogled_chromium@build.opensuse.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/ungoogled_chromium/Ubuntu_Focal/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 02456C79B2FD48BF home:ungoogled_chromium OBS Project <home:ungoogled_chromium@build.opensuse.org>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: What's the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and additional files inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? It looks like you have repos for multiple architectures..

Comment: From the duplicate, it seems you have `apt-file` installed - this downloads additional contents with `apt update`.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the duplicate, this was indeed the problem. `apt-file` removed and I now get `Fetched 8,561 kB in 8s (1,055 kB/s)`.